# Async technique in dropwizard

Tags: multithreading, dropwizard

I have created a POST endpoint using DropWizard.

```java
@POST
@Timed
public String runPageSpeed(@RequestParam String request) {
    try {
        JSONObject requestJSON = new JSONObject(request);
        JSONArray urls = requestJSON.getJSONArray("urls");
        process(urls); // this takes around 10 minutes to complete
        return "done";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new WebApplicationException("failed", Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);

    }
}
```

`process(urls);` takes around 10 minutes to complete, so if we call this endpoint, it takes more than 10 minutes to get the response.

I want `process(urls);` to run in the background after receiving the URLs from the request and immediately return a response to the user.

I tried the following code using threads:

```java
@POST
@Timed
public String runPageSpeed(@RequestParam String request) {
    try {
        JSONObject requestJSON = new JSONObject(request);

        JSONArray urls = requestJSON.getJSONArray("urls");

        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                process(urls); // this takes around 10 minutes to complete
            }
        };
        thread.start();

        return "done";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new WebApplicationException("failed", Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);

    }
}
```

This works, but are there any issues if I use this approach, especially at a high volume?

Comment: Check this out https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/async.html

Answer (score 0):

DropWizard users should promote using *CompletableFuture* for async handling as it is the safest for handling background processing. With *CompletableFuture* you can move the heavyweight task to a background thread and simultaneously continue with the lightweight task thus can also send back a response to the client.

```java
@POST
@Timed
public String runPageSpeed(@RequestParam String request) {
    try {
        JSONObject requestJSON = new JSONObject(request);
        JSONArray urls = requestJSON.getJSONArray("urls");

        CompletableFuture<Void> future = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
            try {
                // perform heavyweight task
                process(urls); // this takes around 10 minutes to complete
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        // perform lightweight task
        return "done";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new WebApplicationException("failed",
                Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

*CompletableFuture* helps in every aspects whether its using the return value of first complex task into second function or notifying on failure with the vast variety of methods it provides

- `runAsync()`
- `supplyAsync()`
- `thenApply()`
- `thenAccept()`
- `thenRun()`
- `exceptionally()`
- `handle()`

You can also chain the *CompletableFuture* using `thenCompose()` and `thenCombine()` which is used when one task is dependent upon others.

Comment: Note, I made the mistake of thinking I could throw from the inner `catch` block. But it seems the logging is about all I could do to capture issues. When I would throw from the async thread, Dropwizard did not catch the exception and log it, like it does for other exceptions thrown from my application's main thread (this was unexpected behavior to me)